# How to Access the SubQuery Result In Trigger

Tags: trigger

```
List<Opportunity> listOpenActivity = [SELECT StageName, Id, (SELECT Id FROM OpenActivities), Probability FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =: Trigger.New];
```

In Above query there is OpenActivities which I would like to access in my Trigger 
can anyone tell me how to access that value

Answer (score 1):

You can use code like this:

```
for (Opportunity o : [
        SELECT StageName, Id, (SELECT Id, Status FROM OpenActivities), Probability
        FROM Opportunity
        WHERE Id in :Trigger.New
        ]) {
    // Access Opportunity object fields via "o" e.g.:
    System.debug(a.StageName);
    for (OpenActivity a : o.OpenActivities) {
        // Access the related OpenActivity object fields via "a" e.g.:
        System.debug(a.Status);
    }
}
```

The list of `Opportunity` objects are iterated over and each one of those has a list of `OpenActivity` objects iterated over via the `OpenActivities` relationship field. Using this style of `for` loop avoids the need for local variables to hold the list references.

See e.g. [A Deeper look at SOQL and Relationship Queries on Force.com](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/A_Deeper_look_at_SOQL_and_Relationship_Queries_on_Force.com) for more detail.

Answer (score 0):

[See the blog for SOQL Subquery](http://raydehler.com/cloud/clod/salesforce-soql-subquery-and-custom-objects-with-apex.html)
You can use a inner query to achive this.

The sample example will be like,

```
List<Account> accountList = [Select Id, Name,(Select id from AccountContactRoles), (Select Id from Contacts)   from Account where Id=: 'some id'];

System.debug('###'+accountList);

for(Account obj : accountList){
    System.debug(':::'+obj.Contacts);
    System.debug(':::'+obj.AccountContactRoles);
}
```